# PHP MySQL dropdown menu with DB's Tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, I have the following code using `PDO` method to get all the tables from my DB.
But I need to put it inside a dropdown menu (the ideia it's to display all the records of the selected table so the user can export that records from the table that he selected to an .csv file)

Can anyone help me please?

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = $pdo->prepare('Show Tables from filecleaner');
$query->execute();

while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     var_dump($rows);
}
```

Comment: but this will show u only tables `Show Tables from filecleaner` all tables. ???

Comment: @devpro yes, when I `var_dump` it shows me all the tables.

Comment: @formador3 show results of var_dump

Comment: and what exactly is your problem? generating a select menu?

Comment: Why don't you simply send `$rows` to the view then loop in it to make the dropdown ? Something like this `<select><?php foreach(){<option></option>} ?></select>`

Comment: @RomainB. I've already tried `echo '<select>';
 echo '<option>'.$row[0].'<br></option>';
 echo '</select>';` but instead of showing all the tables in one dropdown, it create a new dropdown for each table

Comment: Like i said 'loop in `$rows`'

Comment: @kuh-chan yes, generate a select menu where it will display all the tables :s

Comment: To follow your comment it should look like `echo '<select>'; echo '<option>'.$row[0].'<br></option>'; echo '<option>'.$row[1].'<br></option>';echo '<option>'.$row[2].'<br></option>';echo '</select>';`

Comment: @RomainB. but that's exactly what I don't want haha, because that code will create a new combo box for each table, and I want all tables inside one `<select>`

Comment: All the tables will be inside one select that way....

Comment: @formador3 if you can provide the results of your var_dump we could easy help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display all tables name from `filecleaner` in a `select` box like

```
$allTables = array(); // initialize your array
while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){ 
    $allTables[] = $rows[0]; // store all table name in an array. $rows[0] index will give you table name from filecleaner
}
```

then, display like:

```
<select>
    <option>Select Table</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($allTables as $key => $value) {
    ?>
        <option><?=$value?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

**Edit:**

i think you are not getting `$rows[0]` due to `FETCH_ASSOC`, you need to use `FETCH_BOTH` here to get 0 indexed column number.

**Issue in your code is:** `FETCH_ASSOC` returns an array indexed by column name, and you are trying to display with 0 indexed column number.

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)**

Comment: It displays an empty select and the error `Undefined offset: 0` x.x

Comment: @formador3: glad to help u, actually i run a test script with my database, and get the idea, what actually happening. :)

Comment: I should take some time to really learn about all the syntax and debugging hahaha, Thanks ! :)